# Excel Macro Not stopping at last row

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a macro that is building a bubble chart and for each row in the dynamic range it is creating a new series in the bubble chart. I tested the last row calculation was finding the actual last row both manually on the worksheet and with a quick macro to find the last row and display in a message box. So the macro for building the bubble chart is finding the last row correctly. The problem is that the macro is adding in blank series anyway beyond the last row. The macro is adding 10 generic series after the last row.

Macro below:

```
Sub bubble()
'
' bubble Macro for bubble chart
'

Dim Lastrow As Long, ws As Worksheet, wsRD As Worksheet, wsChart As Worksheet
Dim cht As ChartObject, currRow As Integer
Dim ch As Shape, SeriesNum As Integer
   
On Error GoTo ExitSub
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If Left(ws.Name, 12) = "Raw Data SEA" Then
        Set wsRD = ws
    End If
    If Left(ws.Name, 10) = "SEA bubble" Then
        Set wsChart = ws
    End If
Next ws

Lastrow = wsRD.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

  

Set ch = wsChart.Shapes(1)
ch.Name = "SEACht"

SeriesNum = 1
For currRow = 2 To Lastrow
    ch.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    
    ch.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(SeriesNum).Name = wsRD.Cells(currRow, 1)
    ch.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(SeriesNum).XValues = wsRD.Cells(currRow, 2)
    ch.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(SeriesNum).Values = wsRD.Cells(currRow, 4)
    ch.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(SeriesNum).BubbleSizes = wsRD.Cells(currRow, 3)
    SeriesNum = SeriesNum + 1
Next currRow
    
'Format Legend

    ch.Chart.PlotArea.Select
    ch.Chart.SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

'Format X and Y axes

    
    ch.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
    ch.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 0
    ch.Chart.ChartArea.Select
    ch.Chart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    ch.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    
    
' Format datalabels


    ch.Chart.ApplyDataLabels
    ch.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    ch.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).HasLeaderLines = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

' Add charttitle
'

    ch.Chart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    ch.Chart.Paste
    ch.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = _
        "Properties operating exp - RSF and Building Age Factors"
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

ExitSub:
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Checked that the last row calc was actually finding the last row to make sure that was not the issue. Tried recording the process again to see if I missed anything. I didn't see anything that was obvious to change.

Comment: Is `ch.Chart` empty (seriescollection.count = 0) before this runs?

Comment: Having some check to make sure you have content is helpful, e.g.: `If lastRow > sheets(1).usedrange.rows.count then lastRow = sheets(1).usedrange.rows.count`

Comment: Thank you for bringing this up. What was causing the issue is that the blank template with the macro also had an on workbook open call to the macro and when I was opening the blank template it was then saving with blank series and I didn't even realize it so when the macro ran on real data there were already series there.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment and maybe not the source of your problem, but `NewSeries` returns the added series, so you can do this and skip the `SeriesNum` counter:

```vb
Dim rw as Range

For currRow = 2 To Lastrow
    Set rw = wsRD.Rows(currRow)
    With ch.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = rw.Cells(1)
        .XValues = rw.Cells(2)
        .Values = rw.Cells(4)
        .BubbleSizes = rw.Cells(3)
    End With
Next currRow
```